# Ubuntu 18.04 Dual Display with one Display switched through KVM Switch (Keyboard Video Mouse Switch)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg, multiple-monitors, kvm-virtualization

I have two computers (main difference is the graphics main computer has Nvidia GTX 1070 Ti- secondary has Intel HD630) and upgraded to use two monitors.
Only one monitor is switched through the kvm switch.
On one computer (main Desktop with Nvidia GTX 1070) I have problems when I switch back to from the secondary computer to the main computer, then the screen switched through the KVM switch is not detected anymore. Until fall I had a different PC with also Intel graphics that had no problems in this scenario. The secondary computer also has no problems.
I tried to assign the EDID of the second monitor which did not help.

Attached the /etc/X11/xorg.conf from the main computer which (should) work with both monitors.
It works until I switch teh computer for the DP-0 (Dispalyport) display.

```
    # nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings
# nvidia-settings:  version 440.64

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "Module"
    Load           "dbe"
    Load           "extmod"
    Load           "type1"
    Load           "freetype"
    Load           "glx"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "DELL U2715H"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 113.0
    VertRefresh     56.0 - 86.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 1070 Ti"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-2"
    Option         "metamodes" "DP-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0, HDMI-0: nvidia-auto-select +2560+0"

    Option         "CustomEDID" "DP-0:/etc/X11/edid-2717.bin"
    Option         "IgnoreEDID" "false"
    Option         "UseEDID" "true"

    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to save the EDID.bin of each monitor to a file and use it in the configuration.
Usually this should be possible in the xorg.conf, but for me only the file /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-nvidia.conf  worked.

```
Section "OutputClass"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    MatchDriver "nvidia-drm"
    Driver "nvidia"
    Option "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration"
    ModulePath "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/nvidia/xorg"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 1070 Ti"
    Option         "ConnectedMonitor" "HDMI-0,DP-0" 
    Option         "CustomEdid" "HDMI-0:/etc/X11/edid.bin.DP-0:/etc/X11/edid-2717.bin"
    Option         "IgnoreEDID" "false"
    Option         "UseEDID" "true" 
EndSection


Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Screen0"
    Device "Device0"
    Monitor "Monitor0"
    Option "metamodes" "HDMI-0: 2560x1440  +0+0, DP-0: 2560x1440  +2560 +0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
               Depth       24
    EndSubSection

EndSection
```

Now everything works. But take care the 10-nvidia.conf will be overwritten if you change your nvidia driver!